# Advanced "Find in page" in Google Chrome mobile?

Tags: chrome-for-android, google, search, stock-browser, browser-add-ons

Regarding the "Find in page" feature of Android's default and/or Google Chrome web browsers:

[image]

Is there a way to fine-tune the search parameters in order to search for strings with more precision or specificity (i.e. inclusivity/exclusivity)?

[image]

I've tried using [regular expressions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to narrow results, but they don't appear to be supported.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With Chrome for Android, you can't perform "advanced" search for example using regular expression. There are extensions such as [Chrome Regex Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn) or [find+ | Regex Find-in-Page Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find+-regex-find-in-page/fddffkdncgkkdjobemgbpojjeffmmofb?hl=en) that allow to fine tune your searches on a page, but Chrome for Android does not support extensions.

If you are not opposed to the use of other browsers than Chrome, you can use [Yandex browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yandex.browser) or [Kiwi browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser) (they are both based on Chromium. Install one of the extensions mentioned above as you will on your PC, then you will be able to narrow searches on a page.

Comment: It would be nice though wouldn't it. I haven't heard of these other browsers, but I can't think of a reason to only use chrome. It might be worth a look, thanks.